# Migration from Eclipse to Android Studio issues

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to move my project from Eclipse to Android studio.
I have tries 2 methods:

- Importing the current project using the Import in the Android Studio IDE.
- Exporting the current project as a Grade project

(although I do not have grade 
set in my eclipse project) and then importing it to the Android Studio.

With the first method I got gradle and API errors such us:

**No versions available for com.android.support:support-v4:jar**
(I installed the 22 and 23 sdk, none of them fixed the issue).

> Error:(15, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' Possible
>   causes: The project may be using a version of Gradle that does
>   not contain the method. Gradle
>   settings.The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

with the second method in the project explorer I see only the Java src file without the res folders.

**Here is the Gradle code:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to go?
I am doing this basically in order to add the Gradle to my project.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you follow this guide to migrate? https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Comment: Please  provide  your gradle file's code

Comment: Hi @warlock, added the code.

Answer (score 2):

You go with first way and change the android support version.

step:
You go to Open Module Setting then remove the old dependency.
And Select the below support file then sync the project.

Version 23:
support-v4 (com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1)